A question about durable arrow and weapon blanch
A question about durable arrow and weapon blanch. If I weapon blanch a normal arrow with weapon blanch cold iron then treat it to become a durable arrow does the weapon blanch stay with normal use:
Example: Weapon blanch cold iron then treat it with the alchemical glue to make it durable does the Blanch stay after the first use or the blanch stop working. And you have to reapply it ?

"The blanching remains effective until you make a successful attack with the weapon."
This is pretty simple. It has nothing to do with if the weapon is destroyed or not. As per the rules text quoted above, the blanching is used up on a successful attack. For example, you can blanch a sword, which is durable by nature, and the blanching still will be gone after the first successful attack.
You could blanch a durable arrow, or make a blanched arrow durable, but it won't give you a reusable blanched arrow. As soon as you hit with that arrow, the blanching ends.

It may be worth noting that you can make special material Durable arrows. It's not directly answering the question asked, but it would potentially answer the reason it was asked (X-Y Problem)
